# EXCEL VBA UserForm Controls - ZOrder method not working

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a Multipage Userform and several controls on each Page. As the entries of the controls (TextBoxes) are then printed out, the order is important. I now want to change this order by defining/changing the Z-Order.

This was my approach (example for one control)

`Me.Multipage1.Pages(2).controls("tb_hb_komm").ZOrder (1)`

This does not raise any error, but it also does not change my Z-Order.

I also treid using the `.BringToFront` method without any luck ("Method not defined for that object")

Comment: Why do you need to change the zorder for printing?

Comment: It is basically a userform to input labresults. These are then added to a seperate EXCEL sheet in form of a lab report and then it is printed out. The order of the lab results is crucial.

Comment: OK, but why do you have controls on top of each other?

Comment: I don´t quite understand your question sorry. 
It is a ordinary Multipage UserForn. On each Page I have several controls that usualls go like: Label_Labtest1 (text), tb_Labtest1 (textbox), Label_Labtest2 (text), tb_Labtest2 (textbox), and so on.
The order in which they are iterated over in a loop is the z-order apparently, which is defined by the order in which you added the controls. 
As I want to be able to add new Tests at a later point in time, I need to be able to define this order. I hope this is somewhat understandable

Comment: I don't think that's true actually. Given that your controls appear to be numbered, why don't you just use a numeric counter when looping?

Comment: The numbering was just for demonstration purposes. The controls are called Label_leuco, tb_leuco, Label_hb, tb_hb and so on.
I have also tried using the tabindex but failed miserably

Comment: OK, so next question is why does it matter what order the loop goes in? What are you doing with the controls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251547/discussion-between-drevil-and-rory).